# How can I pass a callback to re.sub, but still inserting match captures?

Tags: python, regex

Consider:

```
text = "abcdef"
pattern = "(b|e)cd(b|e)"

repl = [r"\1bla\2", r"\1blabla\2"]
text = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: random.choice(repl), text)
```

I want to replace matches randomly with entries of a list `repl`. But when using `lambda m: random.choice(repl)` as a callback, it doesn't replace `\1`, `\2` etc. with its captures any more, returning `"\1bla\2"` as plain text.

I've tried to look up [re.py](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/re.py) on how they do it internally, so I might be able to call the same internal function, but it doesn't seem trivial.

The example above returns `a\1bla\2f` or `a\1blabla\2f` while `abblaef` or `abblablaef` are valid options in my case.

Note that I'm using a function, because, in case of several matches like `text = "abcdef abcdef"`, it should randomly choose a replacement from `repl` for every match – instead of using the same replacement for all matches.

Comment: Can I see your pattern and some example target text? @ScientiaEtVeritas

Comment: so you're expecting the string returned by the lambda to get another pass by the interp to replace \1 and \2 with the match groups?

Comment: Why not just use `re.sub(pattern, random.choice(repl), text)` ?

Comment: @Todd, that's correct :) Actually it should go through the same procedure string arguments go – but with the string that my ``random.choice(repl)`` call returns. I'm not using ``random.choice(repl)``, because I want a random choice for every match, this one would only make a single random choice, globally, for all matches.

Comment: To get at the match groups programmatically, you'll probably need to do: `mo.group(1)` (first group), `mo.group(2)` - second group.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas I'm struggling to understand your explanation of why Todd's comment is not the correct solution?

Comment: @Nick, if you have several matches (think of ``text = "abcdef abcdef"``), not only a single one (like above ``text = "abcdef"``), it would always use the same replacement, instead of randomly choosing for every match.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas gotcha.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas are all your strings in your repl list the same format? with the same backrefs in the same position for all of them?

Comment: @Todd, they vary and have different backrefs and different numbers of backrefs.

Comment: Ah okay.. Looks like Mark's answer is a perfect fit then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass a function you lose the automatic escaping of backreferences. You just get the match object and have to do the work. So you could:

Pick a string in the regex rather than passing a function:

```
text = "abcdef"
pattern = "(b|e)cd(b|e)"

repl = [r"\1bla\2", r"\1blabla\2"]
re.sub(pattern, random.choice(repl), text)
# 'abblaef' or 'abblablaef'
```

Or write a function that processes the match object and allows more complex processing. You can take advantage of `expand` to use back references:

```
text = "abcdef abcdef"
pattern = "(b|e)cd(b|e)"

def repl(m):
    repl = [r"\1bla\2", r"\1blabla\2"]           
    return m.expand(random.choice(repl))


re.sub(pattern, repl, text)

# 'abblaef abblablaef' and variations
```

You can, or course, put that function into a lambda:

```
repl = [r"\1bla\2", r"\1blabla\2"]
re.sub(pattern, lambda m: m.expand(random.choice(repl)), text)
```

Comment: The expand function is pretty nifty though.

Comment: @Todd maybe a compromise without the comprehension.

Comment: This looks pretty good. He can keep repl the same format and declare it in the function or outside of it. I like it.

Comment: The reason why this is far superior now and actually the only solution that works for me, is that it is independent from the pattern and from the number of match groups. I have a whole bunch of patterns in a list iterating through... :)

Comment: ah yes.. that looks great =) It's actually pretty readable the way you have it now.

Comment: @MarkMeyer +1 for expand. I had forgotten it and it drastically simplifies both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this (and ensure random replacements) is to nest calls to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
text = "abcdef abcdef"
pattern = "(b|e)cd(b|e)"

repl = [r"\1bla\2", r"\1blabla\2"]
text = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: re.sub(r'\\(\d+)', lambda m1: m.group(int(m1.group(1))), random.choice(repl)), text)

print(text)
```

Output varies between

```
abblaef abblaef
abblaef abblablaef
abblablaef abblaef
abblablaef abblablaef
```

It turns out my nested call was basically the equivalent of `m.expand`, as described in [Mark Meyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700187/how-can-i-pass-a-callback-to-re-sub-but-still-inserting-match-captures/60700276#60700276).

Comment: what the ..... <scratches head> ... I didn't see that coming..

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas why do you think this isn't independent of the pattern and the number of match groups?

Comment: @Nick, sorry, it is and works well! :) I misinterpreted ``m1`` as "first matchgroup", similar to Marks previous answer and Todds deleted answer where they used ``m1`` and ``m2`` to reference the two match groups.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas no problem at all. It seems I reinvented `expand` from scratch, so much easier that way! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the capture groups are put back where they were without change.  So change the pattern to use
lookahead and look behind assertions instead:

```
replacements = ['bla', 'blabla']
re.sub(r"(?<=b|e)cd(?=b|e)", lambda mo:random.choice(replacements), text)
```

This matches `cd` if preceeded by a `b|e` and followed by `b|e`.

Alternatively, the replacement function receives a match object, so it has access to all the match groups:

```
re.sub(pattern, lambda mo:f"{mo[1]}{random.choice(replacements)}{mo[2]}", text)
```

where `mo` is the match object, `mo[1]` is the first capture group and `mo[2]` is the second.